# How to open a new tab and scroll down to the specific position with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to develop a chrome extension that can record the current URL and current page coordinates so that I could re-read the site later. I used `chrome.tabs.create` to open the URL in new a new tab but stuck at the scrolling page down step. I tried to use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` and `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to inject some javascript commands to the page, but I don't know how to run scripts only on the specific tab(this method will be applied to every new opened tabs).

this is my manifest.json file↓

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Relay Reader",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "activeTab", "tabs", "webRequest", "scripting"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "description": "Continue reading where you are interrupted",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "32": "images/icon-32.png",
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./scripts/background.js"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*", "http://*/*"
    ]
    
}
```

this is my background.js file ↓

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((tableId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'addMark',
        title: "Bookmark Here",
        contexts: ['all']
    })
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabId},
            func: () => {window.scrollTo(0, 400)}
        });
    }
})

function addMark(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "addMark") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "getSiteInfo" }, (response) => {
            let {siteUrl: url, position: top} = response;
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "example.com"}, () => {})
        })
    }
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(addMark);
```

this is my content.js file ↓

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action == "getSiteInfo") {
        let top = window.scrollY;
        let url = window.location.href;
        
        sendResponse({siteUrl: url, position: top});
    }
})
```